# How to import python git repos as packages

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am having trouble with importing python modules from two git repos as the code was not designed as a package, and there are name collisions which disabled me from being able to use `sys.path.append` in a straight-forward (albeit hacky?) manner.

Note that the problem is not particular of git-repos however I have encountered this problem only in this scenario because of trying to interface with existing work.

The folder structure looks like following:

```
project
  - repo1
    - foo.py
    - bar.py
    - run.py
  - repo2
    - foo.py
    - bar.py
    - run.py
  test.py
```

Both `foo.py` import `bar.py` with `import bar` statements, which works fine as long as you are running the `run.py` scripts in the repo, however if I try to import `repo1.foo` and `repo2.foo` I run into multiple issues.

On attempting the following code

```py
# test.py
import repo1.foo
import repo2.foo
```

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'`, this makes some sense as nothing in the path makes either `bar.py` accessible.

However if I try to append paths 'repo1' and 'repo2' then I can only import either `repo1.bar` or `repo2.bar` depending on order of appends, which is not an acceptable solution.

As the repositories are not my code I would prefer to not change them, but instead wrap them into a namespaced package if possible, however I am unable to find any solutions for the problem.

Comment: I think that I have done this using [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) in the past, have you tried that yet?

Comment: @Bastian I am not too familiar with importlib, however on attempting to use `importlib.import_module` I faced the same issue of ModuleNotFoundError. Can you please share what you did to resolve your problem?

Comment: no I must admit I can't figure it out myself. I may be mistaken and it's not possible with importlib :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**Update::**  As I was depending on this work extensively I published it as a Python package available here: https://pypi.org/project/packagify/ . You can install it instead of copying the old gist.

Add the class from this gist: https://gist.github.com/rijulg/3ea372bef35adb68e27080c949c942af in your code and you can use it as following

```py
from packagify import Packagify
package = Packagify("/home/workspace/my_package")
object = package.import_module("module", ["object"])
object1, object2 = package.import_module("module", ["object1", "object2"])
```

**Methods Tried**

1. Installing the directory as a module using `setuptools`, this did not work as on loading the module various parts inside it threw **ModuleNotFoundError** as they were trying to access siblings without namespaces.
2. Various `importlib` functions, there are a few that allow loading python modules from .py files directly. This might have worked if the modules I wanted to import were contained within a file, but then perhaps there would be other solutions as well. As the problem stood I wasn't able to use this method as the module upon loading wasn't able to locate it's siblings.
3. Adding `sys.path` as mentioned in the question, but I also tried appending the path, loading module and then removing the path before loading the other module. This also did not work because presumably the modules were loaded into python cache and subsequent loads from different directory were ignored because of name clashes.
4. Finally, I noticed something weird happening when I changed the import level using the `__import__` function and I tried the following snippet which worked fine on my toy example. However this still had various issues that I encountered while trying to load the actual repos I wanted to work with. As the solution appeared to be going in the right direction I made the class linked in the gist mentioned a the beginning of the post.

```py
import builtins

original_import = __import__

def my_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level):
    print("my_import", name, globals['__package__'], level)
    try:
        return original_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    except:
        level = level + 1 if globals['__package__'] is not None else level
        return original_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)

builtins.__import__ = my_import

from repo1.foo import main as main_a
from repo2.foo import main as main_b

main_a()
main_b()
```